# Windows Server 2019 VPN Error 8007042a After KB4480116

Tags: windows-server-2019

I am running Windows Server 2019 datacenter with router and remote access for VPN access.  Everything was working fine until I installed the January 8, 2019 update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4480116

After the update, I was unable to start the routing and remote access service and got the following error:

[image: VPN Error]

I can confirm that after I uninstalled the update, the service was able to start.  Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up installing server 2016 to solve my problems.  Even after I uninstalled the update, the vpn service mysteriously stop working again.  Rebooting the server sometimes fixed it but I can not trust this to keep working.  I also had a problem where DHCP was not working either. From other forums I read, lots of people where having the same DHCP problem. Looks like server 2019 is not ready for prime time.  I am going to revisit this in 6 months to see if microsoft fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found temporary solution. NPS service (Network Policy Server) blocks starting RRAS. If you stop NPS, you can start RRAS and after that you can start NPS. If you don't use NPS you can probably disable it.
I've changed service settings to start RRAS Automatic and NPS Automatic (Delayed start), but I can't test it now on production server.
At least you can start it manually if you are in local network and you don't have to reinstall RRAS to get it work.
It was big mistake to install 2019 to the small company. It's the only server so there isn't any older Windows Server.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old question, but this totally helped me. Had identical event logs and error as OP and stopping the NPS service and then starting RRAS fixed the issue. Configured my services as above.

Answer (score 4):

This may cause by NPS bug, here is a solution:

**Go to NPS, find accounting, and click "Change Log File Properties".**

**Disable "If logging fails, discard connection requests".**

It works for me.

Reference:
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/8a29a4b7-5109-49bf-9f4c-db3dfe36b504/nps-bug-on-windows-server-2019?forum=ws2019

Answer (score 3):

Same identical problem.
my workaround is to remove RRAS, restart server, reinstall RRAS and reconfigure VPN access.

It works,.....until next update that make me do the above steps again...…….

No comment about MS behavior about this problem...….

Comment: Glad i'm not the only one with this problem. I tried reinstalling RRAS and it worked fine until I rebooted the server. Hope MS gets this fixed asap!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by changing the dependency of the NPS service so it would know it needed to wait for the RRAS service:

```
sc config IAS depend= RpcSS/RemoteAccess
```

I added the RpcSS dependency as it was already present, please check for yourself if any other dependency is present! (use `sc qc IAS`)

Hope it will help anybody!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem. I forget where I found the fix on the interwebs but you need to run the following command:

Set-RemoteAccessAccounting -DisableAccountingType ExternalRadius

From what I recall, NPS and RRAS if they are on the same server try to write to the same log file. NPS usually starts before RRAS and ends up locking the file which causes the RRAS service to error.

As Gary Wee mentioned

> Go to NPS, find accounting, and click "Change Log File Properties".
> Disable "If logging fails, discard connection requests".

This will resolve your issue if the reverse happens and RRAS starts before NPS and will allow NPS to continue to continue processing requests.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have to restart the following services in this particular order to make it function again:

NLA (Network Location Awareness) (Otherwise my server isn't on the domain network)

Network Policy Server

Routing og Remote Access

Or make a script like this:

net stop NlaSvc

net start NlaSvc

net stop IAS

net start IAS

net stop RemoteAccess

net start RemoteAccess

Answer (score 0):

We've been dealing with this with Server 2019.

We found that the services were starting up in the wrong order.   If you stop NPS service, the RRAS service should start and automatically start NPS as well.

Comment: Wow, this is still an issue even after fully patching the server? I thought MS would have fixed this by now.

Comment: This is still an issue in Server 2022 (!)